# How should "come" and "go" be used here?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

I asked a similar question yesterday: [How should "come" and "go" be used in the following context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/79208/25092)

It's been answered, but I showed the answers to my mom and she gave me this example in response:

Say your friend invites you to a party. The party will be held at your friend's house. At the time your friend asks you, **neither of you are at your friend's house.** Your friend asks "Are you coming (to my party)?" Do you say

> Yes, I'm **coming** / No, I can't **come**

Or

> Yes, I'm **going** / No, I can't **go**

Or do you just say "yes" or "no" to avoid confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be "Yes, I'm **coming** / No, I can't come".
As you are making a direct response to the one who asked the question using the word 'coming to my party', and that you are 'coming' to them at their house.

To another friend, you can say, "I will be **going** to my friends party", as you and the other friend are not yet at the party location and have no direct connection to it, as in, "its not your home/house".

Answer (score 1):

If it is your friend's party, then you say

> **Yes, I'm coming** *(to your party)*
>   **No, I'm not coming** *(to your party)*

**regardless of where you both are**, since you are talking directly to them

If a **third friend** is asking you about your friend's party, then you say

> **Yes, I'm going** *(to their party)*
>   **No, I'm not going** *(to their party)*

regardless of where you are